# Can you save workspaces in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, workspaces

I was wondering if its possible to make a "workspaces image" that I can load back later.

Sometimes I am working on a project and I would like to keep my current layout for when I continue with that. So I'd like to be able to safe my current workspaces, the apps open and the URLs I'm visiting, and get a clean one (one workspace with no open applications). Then when I want to continue with my previous project I just load back those workspaces (after possibly saving the ones I currently have open).

I am not shy of Bash, so solutions which use bash scripts are welcome as well as applications (or missed settings) which achieve this.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I dont have a direct solution, but a workaround is to use a Virtual Machine with ubuntu installed, and use ubuntu's workspaces from there.
When you shut down a virtual machine you can select to save the current state of the machine.

And, in the virtual machine you can have your normal ubuntu workspaces, which will be saved.

You can scroll bottom right in your vm to change workspaces
[image: Scroll bottom right to change workspaces]

That way, when you restart the VM, you will have it as you left it.

Comment: Just for clarification, are you running an Ubuntu VM on Windows or are you running Ubuntu VMs on Ubuntu?
I do think that a VM-esque setup would probably be what I'd end up with (loading the saved "VM" state into my Ubuntu).

Comment: I am on dual boot (linux/windows). i dont have any vm installed at the moment. 
And yes, my idea was that you will end up loading the saved vm states.

Again, for clarification, i meant that you should have an ubuntu vm inside your ubuntu to save/load states.

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood your question.  But I guess no harm even I expose my ignorance.

Will setting up a separate linux user (e.g. project_user) in the same machine help? So whenever you want to continue to work on that project, you just login as that particular user and you will get back all the necessary environments.

Comment: That still wouldn't solve my problem as I'd like this to be persistent even through power cycles.